# ¿"Espero que hagas algo" o "espero hagas algo"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, etimología, conjunciones

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de utilizar este juego de verbos transitivos?

> "Espero que hagas como te ordeno".
>   "Espero hagas como te ordeno".

Es sólo un ejemplo pero tengo la duda porque la segunda forma que he citado siempre me ha sonado incómoda e incorrecta, ¿cuál es la opinión de un experto?

Comment: Suena incorrecto porque **que** es un conector y al suprimirlo la frase queda aislada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se trata de una forma muy poco usada pero válida.

[DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/), artículo “que”, sección [2.1.2](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW#2_1_2):

> Cuando la oración subordinada funciona como complemento directo de un verbo de «ruego» o «temor», se suprime a veces la conjunción *que*: «*Le rogué me permitiera acompañarla hasta la entrada*» (Cano *Abismo* [Col. 1991]); «*Ya me temo no termine nunca* [esta guerra]» (Umbral *Leyenda* [Esp. 1991]); sucede también, aunque más raramente, con verbos de «opinión»: «*El comunicado* [...] *eriza el cabello y supongo habrá espantado al ministro Belloch*» (*Mundo* [Esp.] 21.12.94). En todos estos casos, aunque no se censura la supresión de la conjunción, se considera preferible mantenerla: *Le rogué **que** me permitiera, me temo **que** no termine, supongo **que** habrá espantado*.

Esta otra página, “[Omisión de la conjunción *que*](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Conjunci%C3%B3n%20que%20-%20omisi%C3%B3n.htm)”, se explaya un poco más y da más ejemplos. Copio la entradilla:

> La conjunción *que* en las subordinadas sustantivas, casi siempre de objeto directo, se puede omitir. Esta omisión era frecuente en los textos antiguos y se atestigua hoy en el lenguaje epistolar, en el jurídico y en el administrativo, así como en otras variedades formales de la lengua escrita.

Answer (score 3):

En este contexto *esperar* es un verbo transitivo cuyo objeto directo debe ser siempre un sintagma nominal.

> Espero **tu respuesta**.
>
> **Te** espero con la respuesta.
>
> Espero **que me respondas**.
>
> Espero **recibir** tu respuesta.

Esto implica que si sigue una construcción verbal debe usarse el conector ***que***, o el verbo debe ir en infinitivo, el cual es una forma nominal del verbo. (Esto último si el sujeto del verbo es el mismo sujeto que espera.)

La forma con el verbo finito (conjugado) sin el ***que*** es común

> Espero **me respondas**.

y no sé si se trate de un anglicismo, pero en mi opinión es incorrecta y debe evitarse.